# p-value application in classification

Tags: classification, p-value, standard-deviation, mean

I have applied SVM on my data set for classification using 10-fold cross validation. I've heard we should calculate p-value to know that the mean accuracy is statistically significant. What value should I use for examining p-value? Mean of accuracies of 10-fold cross validation or mean+-standard deviation? Because the p-values of mean is always 1 with the null hypothesis mu=mean(accuracies) but these values for mean+-sd is 0.01151. I'm confused.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should provide a reproducible example, i hardly get what you mean...